# addtoqueue is queueing, but not playing

Tags: deezer

I'm trying to have deezer add songs to the end of the playlist if it's near the end. So obviously, i'm using the addToQueue method to add a few songs to the end of the list.

So far, great success. However, the songs won't play, or at least not without manual intervention. My playlist will stop playing just before the added songs.

The api brings no solution. next(), play(),... no luck!

And then when i click the song in the player, it starts to play.

so euhm, help.

using latest version of chrome and pretty much the example from github.

Comment: Could you post up some code?

Comment: Heya @ninjaPixel. Well, just navigate to http://developers.deezer.com/examples/player_basic.php, open your console and type:  `DZ.player.addToQueue([76077301,76077300]);`  `DZ.player.play();`  you can try doing a `DZ.player.next();` in between, but it won't help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently working on an app with the deezer javascript SDK and having the same problem. I'll keep you updated if we find a way to make it work.

One hack we found and are testing right know is to keep an array of tracks in our javascript code, and on the end of a track using playtrack to play the next one.

Comment: Yep, that was my workaround as well. thank god for the awesome events that bubble :-) Luckily, we don't care about the playlist that is displaying in the player (and additionally, we could just create our own player and hide the deezer one i guess). so this works perfectly. the playTrack method does play the track immediately, so for us, it suffices. Still, it's somewhat annoying that this doesn't work of course :-)

Comment: Seems like they're doing udpates every day, yesterday we could play full songs without paying for an account and today we can't. Seems quite random.

Comment: it depends on the platform @TrauDeRien. on mobile or when no flash is available, you can only stream 30 seconds samples because there's no flash to decrypt encrypted streams. then they fall back to a html5 player with regular urls for the streams, which means you could just download the files, hence the 30 seconds samples. with flash enabled, you get the full songs :-)